# my 2008 ford mondeo will not start at times, any suggestions?

Tags: ford, starting, fuel-system, heater

2008 Ford Mondeo, Diesel  - starting problems.  Issue with starting at times. after long journey it may not start for a few minutes or if its left for 2- 3 days in wet cold weather i may need a jump start yet when battery checked its fine. also get a engine rev every now and then without touching the pedal